# How to format a currency string to float value?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

Iam getting the string like this $2,000.00. Now i want to change this string to float value.
 How to convert this string as float.Actually this string($2,000.00)is coming from formatting number with currency formatter. But now i want to change this string to float value..

Please guide anyone for this.

Thanking in advance.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Consider the string.

```
    NSString *str = @"$2,000.00";
```

Create a number formatter.

```
    NSNumberFormatter *nf = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
```

The ***"important thing"***.

```
    [nf setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterCurrencyStyle];
```

***"Here is what you want".***

```
    NSNumber *number = [nf numberFromString:str];
    float f = [number floatValue];
```

And of course, release the number formatter.

```
    [nf release];
```

Answer (score 0):

NSString objects are the ones that have methods like floatValue. But after removing the $ sign from the string.

Comment: Removing the `$` alone is not enough. He need to remove the comma(`,`) too, in order to get the correct float value.

Comment: ok, i didn't have seen the comma(,) that's why i wrote only $

Answer (score 0):

You could use the same formatter to get an `NSNumber` object representing the float value using `numberFromString:`. The call `floatValue` on the `NSNumber` object.

Comment: iam trying like this, NSString *damount =(NSString *)[aray objectAtIndex:0];
            NSNumberFormatter *formatter =[[NSNumberFormatter alloc]init];
            NSNumber *number= [formatter numberFromString:damount];
            float val=[number floatValue];
            NSLog(@"%0.02f",val);
            o/p:0.00